# Problems creating and using Hotspot in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, broadcom, hot-spot

I know this question has been asked on one too many times and some of you might lable ti as DUPLICATE but i am not able to solve it even after going through those discussions.

This is my `ifconfig` result.

```
    enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:47:47:0b:b2:dd  
          inet addr:10.10.10.86  Bcast:10.10.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8171:8834:551e:d9f1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:66651 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43422 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:77310788 (77.3 MB)  TX bytes:4110183 (4.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:600015 (600.0 KB)  TX bytes:600015 (600.0 KB)

wlp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:d1:b8:d3:b4:bf  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:18
```

My Wifi Driver Seems to be

> Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (wireless 1704 802.11n + BT
>   4.0 )

I tried creating a hotspot from system settings > network option. But upon creating joining that hotspot from my iphone it asks for Password as well as Username. I have tried to put everything in Username but is still not connecting.

Any help?